# Referencing JS and CSS in Firefox Panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to load my html page in a Firefox Panel. I've placed the HTML in the `data` directory. However, my HTML page contains absolute references to the CSS and JS and I noticed that the examples shown use relative references. Is there anyway to use absolute references? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should only use relative references to the files, as ( depending on how resource uri paths are implemented in the SDK ) use of full resource uris can break with future versions of the sdk.

If you absolutely have to, you can get the absolute path by running:

```
var data = require("self").data;
var path = data.url("filename.jpg");
```